# CComboBox DDX_CBString behavior confusing

Tags: mfc

I use a ComboBox control in a Dialog to give the user some useful values (Ex: 10; 20; 100; 400; 800) but let the user insert the exact value if needed.

What I have discovered after long time: 
If I type the value **40** in the Combobox, the Combobox returns after UpdataData() always **400**. :((
Ohterwards with the values **39** or **41**, there is no problem.

That's is not the behaviour what I and the user expected.
When I type a value, ComboBox should take this value, if select from the dropdown Menue, take this.

I see now this behaviour is given by DDX_CBString.

Do I have to write my own DDX_CBString  or is there an another approach?

Code:

```
void CTestDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IFBANDWIDTH, m_cIFBandWidth);
    DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_IFBANDWIDTH, m_sIFBandWidth);  // Bahavior confusing
}

BOOL CTestDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_cIFBandWidth.ResetContent();

    m_cIFBandWidth.AddString(_T("10"));
    m_cIFBandWidth.AddString(_T("20"));
    m_cIFBandWidth.AddString(_T("100"));
    m_cIFBandWidth.AddString(_T("400"));
    m_cIFBandWidth.AddString(_T("800"));


    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}

void CTestDialog::OnBnClickedApply()
{   
    UpdateData(TRUE);     // m_sIFBandWidth now 4 ok!
    UpdateData(FALSE);    // m_sIFBandWidth still 4, but control show 400, so the next OnOk() or Apply() take this value. Wrong!
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to use the GetCurSel method to get the current index and then the GetLBText method to get the text at that index? What is the results then?

Comment: Rather than us guessing, you should post the appropriate code that shows your interaction with the combo box.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle:  in the above code-example: after typing 4 in the ComboBox, GetCurSel is 3 and the GetLBText is "400".
That is not was I expected, it should remains 4.

Comment: The combo is zero based indexing. 0, 1, 2, 3. So 3 is position 4, which has a text value of 400.

Comment: Yes that is clair from the programms perspective, not users perspective. The user typed 4 and get 400!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with modify the DDX_CBtring.

```
void DDX_CBString_Normal(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, CString& value)
{
    ..    
    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
    {
        ..      
    }
    else
    {
        // Behaviour as we expect: Type a value and keep it
        // Select it form dropwon, or take the value the user type it
        AfxSetWindowText(hWndCtrl, value);
        return; 

        /* Disable original MS behavior 
        // set current selection based on model string
        if (::SendMessage(hWndCtrl, CB_SELECTSTRING, (WPARAM)-1,
            (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)value) == CB_ERR)
        {
            // just set the edit text (will be ignored if DROPDOWNLIST)
            AfxSetWindowText(hWndCtrl, value);
        } 
       */
    }
}
```

If anyone has an another aproach let me know.

Comment: If you look at the documents for the select string method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft9e54.aspx it mentions: A string is selected only if its initial characters (from the starting point).

Comment: So, it should be FindStringExact, and then select it based on index. Else, set window text. Bug in the DDX system.

Comment: 40, is not in list. But 400 is. So selectstring picks it.

Comment: Ok, a DDX bug, but why doesnt MS fix it?

Answer (score 2):

New answer to an old question: You don't have to write your own DDX handler, but it's not a bug. `DDX_CBString` intentionally does a partial string compare, whereas `DDX_CBStringExact` is provided which does an exact string compare. The [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991539.aspx) aren't very explanatory about the difference, so I agree it's confusing.

You can just manually change the line to:

```
DDX_CBStringExact(pDX, IDC_IFBANDWIDTH, m_sIFBandWidth);
```

Comment: I was having the same problem with this very unexpected behavior (textbox string not updating when the new value is a prefix substring of an existing value in the listbox). Thanks, this solution fixes it nicely.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks, it helped a lot. (The documentation for the two DDX commands is *identical* !)