# CComboBox not selecting CurSel when dropped down

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, mfc, ccombobox

I have an alphabetically sorted combobox in a dialog. This combo contains multiple strings, but some are duplicated with different cases. i.e. we have an 'On' and an 'ON', an 'Off' and an 'OFF'. This may seem redundant but there is a reason, although this is not important right now.

The duplicates obviously appear one after the other in the list, with the capitalized strings first. i.e.:

> OFF
>
> Off
>
> ON
>
> On

When the user selects the 'On' (lower case), the correct index is set as `CurSel` and the correct string is displayed. However, when I click on the arrow of the combobox to drop down the list, it does not highlight the `CurSel`, but the one previous to it, the capitalized string. See images below.

This is was is selected in the dropdown:

[image: Selected item before dropdown]

This is what is selected in the combobox when expanding the dropdown.

[image: Selected item after dropdown]

I have captured the `ON_CBN_DROPDOWN` message, and checked the cursel value and it is as I expected.

I have also already subclassed this combobox so that I can search for strings in this list in a case-sensitive way, as I know its not implemented normally, so it may be what is causing my issue.

But I don't understand why the string would be overriding the cursel value at this stage? Should the `CurSel` value not be the one used to select the relevant item?

Any ideas on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have tried to capture the `CBN_DROPDOWN` message by overwriting the `OnWndMsg`. When this message occurs, I get the currently selected item (which is the correct item) before dropping down the menu. I then drop the menu, and call `SetCurSel` to what I retrieved before.

```
BOOL CMyComboBox::OnWndMsg(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,    LRESULT *pResult)
{
    if(message == CBN_DROPDOWN)
    {
        int nCurSel = GetCurSel();
        if(nCurSel != CB_ERR)
        {
            ShowDropDown();
            SetCurSel(nCurSel);
            return TRUE;
        }

    }
    return CComboBox::OnWndMsg(message, wParam, lParam, pResult);
}
```

This *kind of* works but when I kill focus, or click on the dropdown arrow again to hide the dropdown, the wrong item is displayed in the text box. Is this a valid method, or am I completely off base here?
What message is sent when the drop down is collapsed?

**EDIT 2:**
I have implemented the case-sensitive combobox from [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1363/Case-sensitive-ComboBox) and it works great.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour with a standard non subclassed combobox ? Can you reproduce this behaviour with other completely non redundant strings such as e.g. "Apple", "Pie", "Foo", "Bar"? I suspect this issue is related to your subclassing stuff.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, I can reproduce this with a non-subclassed combobox. Sorry, the wording isn't clear on that part of the question. I meant to say that since the functionality to find and select strings in the list is only done in a case insensitive way, maybe that's what is causing my issue. Not that subclassing the combobox is the cause.

Comment: Il also could reproduce it with a freshly wizard generated dialog based app and a sorted combo box containing "OFF", "Off", "ON", "On". Looks like an MSBug. But only with the "dropdown" type. With the "droplist" type the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: You may look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287605/hot-tracking-list-item-selection-in-a-combo-box), it deals with hot tracking the selection of a combobox, it could be a start for "fixing" this strange behaviour.

Comment: Recently I found out that the internal mechanism for selecting the entry is not using FindStringExact. It uses SelectString which means it will pick the first entry. So, rather than doing updatedata etc. use: FindStringExact and the SetCurSel with that index. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016759/ccombobox-ddx-cbstring-behavior-confusing/36084144#comment60066655_36084144

Comment: Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1363/Case-sensitive-ComboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comment. I think you will find that the internal mechanics is using **SelectString** to set the index when it is a **dropdown** style.

The side effect is that it may not pick the right entry for you from the list. Therefore, given the nature of the content in your combo, please try this:

```
int iIndex = m_cbData.FindStringExact(-1, "On");
m_cbData.SetCurSel(iIndex);
```

Or

```
int iIndex = m_cbData.FindStringExact(-1, "OFF");
m_cbData.SetCurSel(iIndex);
```

However, be warned, the document for [FindStringExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzf0ht83.aspx) says the search is not case sensitive. But [SelectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft9e54.aspx) (default behaviour) is even worse.

An alternative, which may resolve all of this, is to use **SetWindowText** and do it that way. This way, it does not matter what is in the listbox component. Eg:

```
m_cbData.SetWindowText("On");
m_cbData.SetWindowText("ON");
```

And get the value for the variable by either mapping to a string, or directly using **GetWindowText**.

**UPDATE**: Someone has done the work already! Here is a Case Sensitive ComboBox class:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1363/Case-sensitive-ComboBox

Comment: that's good to know, and explains why I'm seeing what I am. I know FindStringExact is not case-sensitive, and I've overridden this function in my custom combobox class so that it is. It returns the correct index for the string I pass in. But my problem is, that when I drop down the list, the wrong item is selected (due to SelectString not being case-sensitive), but what is placed in the edit box is correct based on this. Would overriding SelectString to make it case sensitive work? This may cause other issues though.

Comment: Yes, I tend to leave existing methods working as they are advertised to work.

Comment: I suppose the elegant solution is to derive from the list box and then override certain event handlers but it is out of my league now ...

Comment: Please look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1363/Case-sensitive-ComboBox

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I don't know how I haven't found that before with all my googling.. I'll give this a go.

Comment: You are welcome. I just tried it with your 4 sets of values and it works a charm.

Comment: That works great. Thanks again Andrew. I'll mark your answer as the solution.